# What's the best way to redirect controller actions in multilingual Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my multilingual Rails 5 app what's the best way to forward a URL like `www.myapp.com/things` to `www.myapp.com/things/new`?

This is my `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    resources :things, :only => [:new, :create]

  end

end
```

I tried doing this in the routes file:

```
get '/things', :to => redirect('/things/new')
```

However, I couldn't get this work with `locales`.

Doing this in the `ThingsController` does work...

```
def index
  redirect_to new_thing_path
end
```

... but seems *wrong* since I have to create an `index` action in my `routes` file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does "I couldn't get this work with `locales`." mean? Any error you can post? what happens if you include the locale in the redirect? `to: redirect('/%{locale}/things/new')`

Comment: Also I guess *Why* seems like a valid question here. If you know that RESTfully `/things` should be an "index" action and you do not have an index action then why would you have a route for "/things"?

Comment: @SimpleLime Nothing happens then because it's not working. I used the same code as yours. It's what I meant by `locales`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Good point actually. I want my app to be as user friendly as possible I guess. In the case of my app, people tend to play around with the URLs a lot.

Comment: I would say let them "play around" all they want but a 404 is still a 404 e.g. should you then allow for "/thing" and "/stuff" and *"[/]Do you also say Froderick?"* ? If they enter a path that is not valid then isn't a 404 is more appropriate than a *"Is it me you're looking for?"* routing pattern? At most I would suggest a catch all route and redirect to root (with a flash message maybe?)